# Load UITableViewController before webservices

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, uitableview

I am trying to load the data from `web-services` and insert into the `UITableViewController`.

I can do this successfully but the problem is, it will 'hang' for a short period at the first UIView before going to the `UITableViewController`, when it is loading the `web-services` from the internet. It will `hang` longer if the internet speed is slow.

Any chance I can showing up the empty `UITableViewController` first with a 'Loading' sign and then only start retrieving the data from `web-services` and reload the table?

Currently, I put the function used to call `web-services` in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self._completeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self._completeList = [self getListFromWebServices];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best approach as my suggestion you have to use [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) like bellow as example

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       //code for webservices calling

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           //reload you tableview here
           [self.tableview reloadData];
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be storing data in array and in numberOfRows method using array.count.

You should alloc init array in viewDidLoad and start secondary thread to download data from net.

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getListFromWebServices) withObject:nil];
```

When download is complete call table reloadData on main thread.

```
[self.table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

So before downloading dataArray count would be zero and you will get blank table

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to move these two lines of code into -(void)viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self._completeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
  self._completeList = [self getListFromWebServices];
  // Assuming that [self getListFromWebServices] is a blocking call.
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But I would recommend to load your data async using GCD:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) { 
      _completeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self._completeList = [self getListFromWebServices];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
      });
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Durgaprasasad Ans:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        aResult = [self getListFromWebServices];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateMyUIWithResult: aResult];
        });    
    });
```